# How to write a sql trigger correctly

Tags: sql-server

I want to add a trigger and I never wrote one.
When I update or add a new values to my table, I want to check that some value is allowed.
I started the trigger but I don't really know how to end it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER isAguide
ON tblDiving 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Found bit
select @Found = count(*)
from tblAuthorized 
WHERE diver_number = @id 
    and level_name = 'guide'
```

I want to allow adding ONLY if @found=1.
@id is the value that the user is trying to add to the table.
So first, how do I get the value the user entered in this 'id' Column?
And second, How do I continue the trigger I wrote?
Is it ok I chose AFTER INSERT?
I want to add something like:

```
if(@found=1) THEN allow adding/updating
else don't allow.
```

Ty

Comment: `set @id = (select id from inserted)`?

Comment: @MarcB
Ty. What about the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing a trigger I'd recommend to create a separate table "Guides" with the diver number in there as the only column (being a primary key).
Add a foreign key reference to the related Id column of your tblDiving table.

Not only will this be compliant with a normalized data structure, it'll also be faster.

Finally you'll need to consider the scenario of changing the level_name of a diver_number from 'guide' to something different after there are some rows inserted into the tblDiving table. How do you want the app to react?

Comment: I wish I could.
It's an assignment for the university, we have to use a trigger..

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an AFTER trigger you can throw an error and roll back the transaction if the id is not found.

```
CREATE TRIGGER isAguide
ON tblDiving AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Found bit, @id int;

    SET @id = SELECT id FROM inserted;
    SET @Found = 
        (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM tblAuthorized 
        WHERE diver_number = @id 
        AND level_name = 'guide'
        );

    IF @Found = 0
    THEN
       RAISERROR ('The ID entered is not valid', 16, 1);
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
       RETURN 
    END;
END;
```